# SQL - complicated link table, no simple solution

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am working on a project that has a relatively complicated data structure, and we are a bit stumped with the following situation:

The db has various tables which represent glazing unit* components (glass pane, coating, blind) and each one of these components has a spectra. (* glazing unit - think double/triple glazing glass unit)
Now we could have one spectra table per component table, and there would be a simple FK relationship, as follows:

```
tbl_glasspane    1 -- many   tbl_glasspane_spectra
-------------                -------------
+ Id                         + GlassPane_Id
  GlassPaneName              + Wavelength
  TypeId etc.                  Value
```

Where GlassPaneId is a primary key in GlassPane, and GlassPaneId/Wavelength is a composite primary key in tbl_spectra.

This works fine, however we would need one tbl_xxx_spectra for each component table.

The solution to this was to have one Spectra table that each of the component tables would reference, but therein lies the problem - how do I get an arbitrary number of component tables to reference one spectra table?

My initial solution was:

```
tbl_spectra          tbl_spectraIndex    tbl_glasspane       tbl_coating
---------------      ---------------     -------------       -------------
+ SpectraIndex_Id    + Id                + Id                + Id
+ Wavelength                               SpectraIndex_Id     SpectraIndex_Id
  Value
```

So an explanation...

tbl_spectraIndex is a table which contains one identity column. tbl_spectra has a FK relationship between Id from tbl_spectraIndex and SpectraIndex_Id, and this is one part of the composite PK for tbl_spectra. tbl_glasspane and tbl_coating have a FK relationship to tbl_spectraIndex.

Is this a sensible solution?

Answer (score 0):

In this kind of cases is better to use a de-normalized schema. You could use one single spectra table with two fields: one is an int that store the kind of object (Table) the spectra belongs to. The other is an int that link to the table ID. In this cases spectra table is linked to multiple tables with the same field. I tend to do this for example with my address table. In my database I have many objects that need to have one or more address object asociated, while every address has the same fields. So i create a single address table, with two field like i mention early, one to represent the kind of object to represent, and one with the link to the actual object.

Also have you consider putting all you glazing tables into one single big table? Hope it helps you.